# How to compare special time units like this in python？

Tags: python

```py
time1=1.6h
time2=8.7m
time3=10.2s
time4=3.3ms
time5=136.6micros
```

**result:** time1 > time2 > time3 > time4 > time5

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import datetime

time1 = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1,minutes = 36)
time2 = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 8, seconds = 42)
time3 = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 10, milliseconds = 200)
time4 = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds = 3, microseconds = 300)
time5 = datetime.timedelta(microseconds = 136.6) #This will be rounded up to Microseconds

if time1 > time2 > time3 > time4 > time5:
    print ("Condition True")
else:
    print ("Condition False")
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `timedelta` gave me a solution

Answer (score 1):

I recommend for you to reformulate your question. You would need to create a conversion function and store the time in a specific time unit for you to compare the results. This seems to be a school assigment, so I won't recommend any code yet, but you can do the following:

1. Create a function in which you input a numerical value and a unit identifier in the form of a string.
2. Have the function return the equivalent value in a specific time unit (preferably seconds)
3. Perform the comparissons you need to do for your assignment.

Comment: or even better a class